# Sum rows by a value and remove duplicate rows in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi im having the followig table:

columns : word, docNum, frequency

example rows:

```
ana,0,1
bob,1,2
ana,0,3
pen,2,2
```

i would like to update my table by removing the duplicate lines and suming the "Frequency" value.
so the output would be:

```
ana,0,4
bob,1,2
pen,2,2
```

I dont want to use a temp table. can you help me in writing the Mysql query?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a temp table?  Basically, you're asking for an update and delete operation in one query, which doesnt exist.  You need to store your interim information somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with two separate commands, an `update` and a `delete`:

```
update table t join
       (select word, docnum, sum(frequency) as freq
        from table t
        group by word, docnum
       ) tsum cross join
       (select @rn := -1) hack
    t.frequency = tsum.freq + (@rn := @rn + 1);

delete t
    from table t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table t2
                      where t2.word = t.word and
                            t2.docnum = t.docnum and
                            t2.frequency > t.frequency
                     );
```

The `update` statement sets the frequencies to increasing values for each word/docnum pair.  The `delete` then deletes all but the smallest value.

As a note, I would never use this logic.  Instead, I would simply do:

```
create temporary table tsum as
        select word, docnum, sum(frequency) as freq
        from table t
        group by word, docnum;

truncate table t;

insert into t(word, docnum, frequency)
    select word, docnum, freq
    from tsum;
```

Comment: I tried to execute this part and the mysql server finds some error: create temporary table tsum as
        select word, docnum, sum(frequency) as freq
        from table t
        group by word, docnum;

Comment: the word `table` in first query is wrong..

i mean:
"create temporary table tsum as
        select word, docnum, sum(frequency) as freq
        from t
        group by word, docnum;........"

Comment: @user2812912 . . . `table` in the `update` statement is intended to refer to your table.

Comment: I understand that. That really worked in SQL code. When executed that statement in Java jdbc, i had to remove the 'table' word. Thank you for your help!